# Выборка из двух таблиц с чередованием

Tags: php, sql

Можно ли с помощью одного запроса выбрать из двух таблиц БД и упорядочить чередованием, т.е чтобы в итоговой выборке записи чередовались (2 из 1,2 из - 2 и т.д) ?

Comment: укажите диалект sql, и выходит вам надо две из первой, две из второй и так далее? или что? в любом случае вам тут нужен юнион для таблиц, и нумерация строк в них. затем сортировка

Comment: Как выбрать из двух таблиц я знаю, мне нужно еще упорядочить выбранные записи чередованием также через запрос.

Comment: если структуры таблиц одинаковы - используйте (SELECT * FROM table1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table2) с нужным LIMIT
упорядочить - отсортировать?

Comment: мне нужно выбрать уже данные с учетом чередования

Comment: Например можно взять номер строки, начиная с 0 и сбросить младший бит (`& 0xFFFFFFFE`) (или вычитанием остатка от деления на 2). Получим номера 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, ... Из второй таблицы то же самое но +1. Остается сделать union и отсортировать по этому полю. А вот как именно получать номера строк зависит от диалекта sql. в MySQL до 8 версии придется воспользоваться переменными. В 8 версии MySQL и в подавляющем большинстве других СУБД можно использовать функцию row_number()